# PHP SimpleXML Xpath Relative to Current Node Only

Tags: php, xpath, simplexml

I am trying to run a simple PHP SimpleXML command using xpath. But, my `//w:pStyle` Xpath is getting all nodes in the entire document and not the ones relative to the node `//w:p` thats being looped. **Note:** I want to keep the loop for both xpaths separate. I do not want to have both under one xpath i.e. loop through the paragraph nodes and then loop the styles nodes only in that paragraph if they exist.

```
 foreach($file->xpath('//w:p') as $p){
  echo 'Paragraph';
  $styles=$p->xpath('//w:pStyle');
  foreach($styles as $style){echo 'Style';}
 }
```

The xpath `//w:pStyle` selects all the `w:pStyle` nodes. I would like instead for it to select the ones that are relative to the paragraph node. What is the solution here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is, that you are selecting elements from the whole document by prefixing the expression with `//`. You should prefix it with `.//` instead, like this

```
$styles=$p->xpath('.//w:pStyle');
```

which will select all `w:pStyle` descendants of the `w:p` element.
If you only want direct children of `w:p`, use

```
$styles=$p->xpath('w:pStyle');
```

since `w:pStyle` is a child of `w:pPr` which is a child of `w:p`, you could use

```
$styles=$p->xpath('w:pPr/w:pStyle');
```